# How to make a specific string into a palindrome

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, list

I have a string of lowercase letters and should determine the index of the character whose removal will make the string a palindrome.
Examples:

aaab    3 -> If i remove the char at index 3 will get -> aaa

baa     0 -> Removing b will give the palindrome aa

Comment: What did you try? We're not here to make some homework ;-)

Comment: LOL - @JeroenvanLangen maybe we should give it a go.

Comment: Yes, sure i was wondering if there is any short solutions using LINQ, but cant figure it out :(

Comment: Try to itreate over the string and remove each char and then recheck for palindrome.

Comment: `var a = "string"; return new string(a.Concat(a.Reverse()));`

Answer (score 1):

If you know that only a single character would be required to be removed in order to form a palindrome, then you could simply iterate through the list and see when you meet that criteria :

```
// Loop through your index values in your string
for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
      // If you removed a certain character, would it form a palindrome?
      if(IsPalindrome(input.Remove(i,1)){
           // If so, return the index
           return i;
      }
}
```

Likewise, if you wanted to *always* ensure that is a string is a palindrome, you could use its definition and simply concatenate it with its reverse :

```
public string MakePalindrome(string s)
{
    // This will concatenate your string with it's reverse (i.e. ab => abba)
    return String.Concat(s,s.Reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complex but you will get a required output.

```
 public string GetPalindrom()
    {
        string strInput = "aaab";
        string strDistinct = new String(strInput.Distinct().ToArray());
        int intOccurence = 0;
        string outputString = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < strDistinct.Length; i++)
        {
            intOccurence = 0;
            foreach (var item in strInput)
            {
                if (item == strDistinct[i])
                    intOccurence++;
            }
            if (intOccurence == 1)
            {
                outputString = strInput.Remove(strInput.IndexOf(strDistinct[i]),1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return outputString;
    }
```